# wget converting or altering .jar file on the fly?

Tags: 18.04, wget

I am very new to Linux and trying to use this application server named Lucee.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04.  The instructions I am following say to download the application using wget.

When I run this command:

```
wget http://release.lucee.org/rest/update/provider/loader/5.3.1.102
```

**in my browser**, I get a `.jar` file.

When I run it **from my linux terminal** it does download the file, but it removes the `.jar` extension because when I do an `ls` in the `/tmp` directory all I see is "5.3.1.102"

How do I prevent it from being converted or altered if possible?

Comment: Or the server might be misconfigured and sending different headers to browsers and command-line clients. Won't be the first time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the original file location is https://cdn.lucee.org/lucee-5.3.1.102.jar redirected to the url on your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hard link that you can see in the `wget` output... although you can download it (other version maybe) from the downloads page. Why don't you?

```
wget http://release.lucee.org/rest/update/provider/loader/5.3.1.102 
--2020-04-23 22:33:36--  http://release.lucee.org/rest/update/provider/loader/5.3.1.102
Resolving release.lucee.org (release.lucee.org)... 205.210.189.210
Connecting to release.lucee.org (release.lucee.org)|205.210.189.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://cdn.lucee.org/lucee-5.3.1.102.jar [following]
```

Then:

```
wget https://cdn.lucee.org/lucee-5.3.1.102.jar
```